# How do I find the commands that the Windows GUI executes in the background?

Tags: windows, command-line

For example if I press the shutdown button in the GUI, the shutdown command is executed in the background. How would I look that up? Is there maybe a history of OS commands?

When I look up the history in the command line, it is just the history of the commands I executed.

Comment: It's not necessarily a command. In this particular case it's https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-exitwindowsex. But why would you need that information? Because (based on how the question is asked), I have the feeling that even if you had it, you wouldn't know what to do with it.

Comment: So that means that the GUI and the command line run the function directly? I thought that the Windows GUI is built on top of the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows does not call shutdown.exe to shutdown, it just calls the `ExitWindowsEx` API function directly.

To find out which API function Explorer.exe calls, you need to use a [debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/getting-started-with-windbg) or [API Monitor](https://apimonitor.com/)...